# Someone touched my div and now a from won´t allign properly

Tags: css, html

I am quite frustrated right now. I was done with my work for school when someone in my class touched my code I tried ctrl+z but the damage was already done and I wan´t able to pinpoint it.

Basically I had to forms with submits displayed inline, but now they have a weird break between and also they´re moving outside the div. I tried using inline again  but to no avail.

HTML

```
     <div class="popUp1 hide" id="popUpCorrecto1">
        <div class="estiloPopUp">
          <span>Información de laboratorio</span>
          <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
        </div>

            <ul>
       <li>BLA</li>
       <li>BLA</li>
       <li>BLA</li>
       <li>BLAr</li>
    </ul>

    <form class="labOption" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name = "btnEliminar" 
               id="btnModificar"   value="Modificar" >
    </form> 

    <form class="labOption2" method="post">
             <input type="submit" name = "btnModificar" 
                 id="btnEliminar" value="Eliminar" >
   </form>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
   .popUp1{
 border-style: groove; border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #2c3e50;
 position: absolute;
 width:256px;
 height: 256px;
 background-color: #ecf0f1;
 top: 190px;
 left: 550px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 z-index: 1000;
}

 #popUpCorrecto1 p{
position: relative;
left:37px;
top: 60px;
width: 180px;
}
 #popUpCorrecto1 input{
position: relative;
top:110px;
left: 45px;
margin: 0 96px 0 0;

 }
 .estiloPopUp{

background-color: #f39c12;
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
height: 30px;
border-collapse: collapse;


}

 #popUpCorrecto1 span:nth-child(1){
position: relative;
font-size: 17px;
color:#fff;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
top: 5px;
 }      

   #popUpCorrecto1 span:nth-child(2){
position: relative;
float:right;
padding: 5px;
bottom: 5px;
color:#000;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
cursor: pointer;

 }

 .show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

 .display{
display: inline;

 }

 #labOption{
display:inline;
}

 #labOption{
display:inline;
 }

 #btnModificar{
float: left;

}

 #btnEliminar{
float: right;

 }
```

Any ideas would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having us fix your homework won't help you learn.

Comment: "Someone touched my divs" - hilarious

Comment: Who touched Sasha? **Who touched my `<div>`?**

Comment: Congratulations, you have successfully learned the importance of [Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Comment: Please don't laugh guys, the divs may now need counselling

Comment: All joking aside, just take a step back, and look at the html/css in Firebug or similar, I'm sure you will quickly be able to find the issue.

Comment: I used Firebug and it didn´t work because the *censored* who did this changed literaly one value, it was like searching a needle in a haystack!

Comment: As a side comment guys I´ll have you know that my <div> is making fast recovery, it still doesn´t like to talk about the incident but we are taking it one minute at time.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 }#popUpCorrecto1 input{
position: relative;
top:80px;
left: 40px;
margin: 0 23px 0 0;
```

This is what was wrong someone changed my previous value pof 80px for something else.

;D

Answer (score 1):

look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/AFwSU/)

change

```
 #btnEliminar{
float: right;
}
```

to

```
#btnEliminar{
float: left;
 }
```

Also, can you add your code/ examples to jsFiddle/similar so that it is easier for others to look at rather than just posting code? just looking at code doesn't help debugging.